# Plotting time series in R, How to format the x-axis date-time value using 12 hour clock data

Tags: r

I have a dataset from two pressure loggers I'm trying to compare by plotting a time series. The data looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(log1=rnorm(15,100,1),
                   log2=rnorm(15,101,1),
                   datetime=strptime(as.character(c('12/19/2019 10:30:00', '12/19/2019 10:45:00',
                                           '12/19/2019 11:00:00', '12/19/2019 11:15:00',
                                           '12/19/2019 11:30:00', '12/19/2019 11:45:00',
                                           '12/19/2019 12:00:00', '12/19/2019 12:15:00',
                                           '12/19/2019 12:30:00', '12/19/2019 12:45:00',
                                           '12/19/2019 01:00:00', '12/19/2019 01:15:00',
                                           '12/19/2019 01:30:00', '12/19/2019 01:45:00',
                                           '12/19/2019 02:00:00')), format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
data
```

I have tried using as.ts(), as.POSIXct, and strptime() functions as well as creating a separate column for time and date and creating time vectors using the 'chron' package but the plots consistently treat the values for PM as AM (because the logger does not record on a 24 hr clock). Here's the plot code:

```
plot(data$datetime, data$log1, type = 'l')
par(new=T)
plot(data$datetime, data$log2, type = 'l', col='red')
```

As you can see the plot "jumps" backwards because the time values after 1:00PM are considered as AM. I'm hoping that someone can suggest a way to format these data so that I may plot time series using the data as downloaded from the logger so that R recognizes AM/PM, or perhaps a way to add an IF statement to add 12 hours to my PM times. The raw data does come with AM/PM designations but these are not recognized in any format that I can find in R.

Thank you

Comment: Is AM/PM available? That is, is the paste above just a subset not including AM or PM?

Comment: Per help file for `strptime`, format `%I:%M:%S %p` if you do have the AM / PM.

Comment: If the AM/PM is not available, can you use an index to assign AM/PM values?  It looks like your logger is recording at regular intervals, so could you assign AM values to the first 48 records per day, then PM for the next 48 records each day?  Then you should be able to paste that in with your datetime column and then render back to a date/time format.

Comment: @markhogue I do have AM/PM designations and that format worked, I had to change the %H to %I in order for it to not throw an error when plotting, thanks.